# XmlWriter writing empty xmlns

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter

I'm using the following code to initialise an XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument moDocument = new XmlDocument();
moDocument.AppendChild(moDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null));
moDocument.AppendChild(moDocument.CreateElement("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"));
```

Later in the process I write some values to it using the following code

```
using (XmlWriter oWriter = oDocument.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
  oWriter.WriteStartElement("Placemark");
  //....
  oWriter.WriteEndElement();
  oWriter.Flush();
}
```

This ends up giving me the following xml when I save the document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark xmlns="">
    <!-- -->   
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

How can I get rid of the empty xmlns on the Placemark element?

**--EDITED TO SHOW CHANGE TO HOW PLACEMARK WAS BEING WRITTEN--**
If I put the namespace in the write of placemark then non of the elements are added to the document.

Comment: Why do you want a filled xmlns? the namespace is the same of the parent node.

Comment: @onof - I don't want a filled xmlns, I tried without to begin with and then with thinking it was better. See revised code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by creating the document with the following code (no namespace in the document element)

```
XmlDocument moDocument = new XmlDocument(); 
moDocument.AppendChild(moDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null)); 
moDocument.AppendChild(moDocument.CreateElement("kml"));
```

And by saving it with the following code to set the namespace before the save

```
moDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", msNamespace);
moDocument.Save(msFilePath);
```

This is valid as the namespce is only required in the saved xml file.

Comment: It may be valid, but it's bad practice.

Comment: @Jason - Unless you can offer a 'good' way to do this then this is not 'bad' practice; it is the only way to achieve this!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but just to prevent future bad practice; you should **never** declare the *xmlns* namespace in an XML document, so this may be the cause why you get empty nodes since you are doing something the XmlDocument is not supposed to do.

> The prefix xmlns is used only to declare namespace bindings and is by
>   definition bound to the namespace name http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/.
>   It MUST NOT be declared . Other prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this
>   namespace name, and it MUST NOT be declared as the default namespace.
>   Element names MUST NOT have the prefix xmlns.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me ([source](http://qaru.site/questions/51427/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net)):

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("","");
s.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialize, ns);
```

Answer (score 0):

`oWriter.WriteStartElement("Placemark");` should work, because the parent node already has the right namespace.

Comment: That was how I had the code initially and it gives the empty xmlns. I've changed my code to reflect this, putting the namespace in the write of placemark actually will not allow the elements to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
oWriter.WriteStartElement("kml", "Placemark", "kml");
```

Comment: I take it u meant kml not klm; edited on this assumption. This still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You needed

```
oWriter.WriteStartElement("Placemark", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
```

otherwise the Placemark element gets put in the null namespace, which is why the `xmlns=""` attribute is added when you serialize the XML.

Comment: You mean you do this, and it still serializes with xmlns="" on the Placemark element? Or something else?

Comment: Even if you do that you still get xmlns="" on the Placemark element.